# Can a WCF Data Service be hosted by something other than IIS?

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

Is it possible to host a WCF Data Service with the ServiceHost class as you can with WCF services or Workflow Services? If not, what limits it from being hosted in that manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You'll have the best luck with using the `DataServiceHost` as described in [this MSDN reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668805.aspx).

Comment: +1 here's a pretty nice article on a dynamic loading host. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/generic_wcf_host.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following article.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/1764/Default.aspx

This explains how to create a Data Service from scratch and then host it in a console application.

Hope this might give you some insights into how this can be done.